# Div not centering bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can't center the following created using bootstrap so bootstrap based solution is a welcome:

```
<div class="facts"> 

  <!-- Factor -->
  <div class="col-xs-3 fact"> 
    <!-- Fact Left --> 
    <a class="fact-icon"> 
    <!-- Fact Icon --> 
    <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> </a> 
    <!-- Factor Area -->
    <div class="fact-number" data-perc="129"> 
      <!-- Factor -->
      <h1 class="factor light"></h1>
      <!-- Factor Description -->
      <h3 class="light uppercase">Clients Registered</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- End Factor Area --> 
  </div>
  <!-- End Factor --> 

  <!-- Factor -->
  <div class="col-xs-3 fact"> 
    <!-- Fact Left --> 
    <a class="fact-icon"> 
    <!-- Fact Icon --> 
    <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> </a> 
    <!-- Factor Area -->
    <div class="fact-number" data-perc="3125"> 
      <!-- Factor -->
      <h1 class="factor light"></h1>
      <!-- Factor Description -->
      <h3 class="light uppercase">Emails Sent</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- End Factor Area --> 
  </div>
  <!-- End Factor --> 

  <!-- Clear -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fun-acts .fun-acts .facts .fact {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

.facts {could'nt find any style computed style shows max-width:1170}

Please help

UPDATe :

Image of structure:
http://s3.postimg.org/onkmji1df/2014_03_27_20_26_48_Inbox_All_Mailing_Software.png

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
#fun-acts .fun-acts .facts .fact {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: no does'nt work, i have uploaded a image of structure for help.